# Proving by induction, involving a binomial coefficient and an inequality.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction, binomial-coefficients

For this week I was asked to prove the following by mathematical induction:
$\sum_{k=0}^m {{m}\choose{k}}y^k \leq (m+1)!$ with $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

Now for my P(M+1) part, I have tried to merely replace m by it, such that I obtain: $\sum_{k=0}^{M+1} {{M+1}\choose{k}}y^k$ and then using the fact that ${{M+1}\choose{k}}={{M}\choose{k}}+{{M}\choose{k-1}}$ has not yielded the desired result. Is there anyone who could help me a step in the right direction? I just have no clue what to do, to be honest. I am pretty bad with thinking in terms of binomial coefficients (and especially whenever you do a summation from 0 to M).

Hopefully someone is willing and able to help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm confused, the left expression contains $y$, and the right expression doesn't.

Comment: That is correct, but you made me aware of the fact that I indeed forgot something. y is said to be as follows: $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

Thank you for pointing it out! From here on it should be possible with induction, I believe.

Comment: The left-hand side is $(1+y)^m$ (prove it by induction); then you just need to prove that $2^m\le (m+1)!$.

Comment: That one is an eye opener to me. Thank you! I think I will be able to do it now.